# Cant find Icons in material pallete-com

Tags: flutter, icons, material-design, pallet

I'm searching for some icons for a flutter app.
materialappPallete.com was introduced to me. but I can't find any icon part in.
please guide me how can I have access to the icon part?
thanks

Comment: The link in your question is broken. Your question is not well understandable

Answer (score 0):

You can search for icon [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Icons-class.html) and find the name for the icon then use that name with

```
Icons.name
```

Moreover, you can use [FontAwesomeIcons](https://pub.dev/packages/font_awesome_flutter) package for icons as well.

Answer (score 0):

**[pngrepo](https://www.pngrepo.com/) This is a good website to get icons from...**
Download the Icon you like and then add it to the YAML file in order to be able to use it

Comment: Thank you friend. I think materailpallete has updated the website and contents, which some of them are not available any more. was hopping  some one be familiar and working with Materialpallete,